# How can using Python backslash line continuation be subtly wrong?

Tags: python, syntax, backslash

[This section](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements) of the Python docs describes a subtle error that can happen when using backslash line continuation, if you accidentally add a space after the backslash.

It says, the following would be a syntax error (with a space after the backslash):

```
if foo.bar()['first'][0] == baz.quux(1, 2)[5:9] and \ 
   calculate_number(10, 20) != forbulate(500, 360):
      pass
```

...but that the next snippet would just be subtly wrong (with a space after the backslash):

```
value = foo.bar()['first'][0]*baz.quux(1, 2)[5:9] \ 
        + calculate_number(10, 20)*forbulate(500, 360)
```

I tried to reproduce this with this:

```
value = 1 + 2 \ 
        + 3 + 4
```

but got this:

```
  File "foo.py", line 1
    value = 1 + 2 \
                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Under what circumstances would that accidentally-added space not be a syntax error?

Comment: This is also stated in [PEP-3125](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3125/): *"Also note that the \ must be the final character in the line. If your editor navigation can add whitespace to the end of a line, that invisible change will alter the semantics of the program."* No explanation, though.

Comment: Yep. You must have space or tab after "\"

Comment: I'd say the doc is wrong. Since at least python 2.4, this is caught as a syntax error.

Comment: Much of the Howtos section is dated or outright wrong.  I would take most of it with a grain of salt.