# Is line continuation with backslash dangerous in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, backslash

I understand that current best practice for line continuation is to use implied continuation inside parenthesis. For example:

```
a = (1 + 2
     + 3 + 4)
```

From PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

I intend to follow this convention going forward, however, my question regards how worried I should be about bugs in existing code that continues lines with a backslash:

```
a = 1 + 2 \
    + 3 + 4
```

The python docs (https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements) warn that a stray space at the end of a line after the backslash can make the code "subtly wrong," however, as pointed out in this question ([How can using Python backslash line continuation be subtly wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368510/how-can-using-python-backslash-line-continuation-be-subtly-wrong)), the example given simply results in a SyntaxError being raised which is not a subtle problem as it is easily identified. My question, then, is do there exist cases where continuing a line with a backslash causes something worse than a parsing error? I am interested in examples where a mistake in backslash continuations yields a runtime exception or, worse, code that runs silently but with unintended behavior.

Comment: As someone else pointed out in the comments of the linked question, the how-to is outdated, an extra space after the backslash is now a syntax error. So it's not dangerous, just bad style.

Comment: I'd say it can be "subtly wrong" in the sense that the error can not easily be spotted _in the code itself_, just by reading.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you start the second line with the same indentation as the first line and then accidentally delete the backslash: No syntax error and a wrong result:

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yes, this is similar to the question I link, however, mine is more broad in that I'm asking about errors coming from backslash continuation generally rather than specifically from a trailing space. Also, the statement of my question is more specific in that it doesn't hinge on the meaning of "subtly wrong." I'm asking specifically if mistakes can lead to run time exceptions or code the silently runs with unexpected behavior.

Comment: @jbch, do you (or anyone else) know if a trailing space after a backslash used to be valid syntax? I could see part of the answer being that this used to be a source of dangerous silent bugs but that a modification of the parser to raise a syntax error fixed this.

Comment: @gregrf The comments in the linked issue say it started to be a syntax error in 2.4 but I havn't verified this myself.

Comment: @jbch, are you referring to tdelaney's comment, "Since at least python 2.4, this is caught as a syntax error?" I take that to mean he's tried it in Python 2.4 and knows it raises a syntax error but doesn't know about previous versions.

Answer (score 7):

"Subtly wrong" is subjective; each has her own tolerance of subtlety.

One often-cited example of possibly harmful line continuation, regardless of `\`-separated or implicit, is the continuation of strings in a container structure:

```
available_resources = [
    "color monitor",
    "big disk",
    "Cray"
    "on-line drawing routines",
    "mouse",
    "keyboard",
    "power cables",
]
```

Do the available resources include a Cray supercomputer, or `Crayon-line drawing routines`? (This example is from the book "Expert C Programming", adapted for Python here).

This code block isn't ambiguous, but its visual appearance created by continuation + indentation can be deceptive, and may cause human error in understanding.

Comment: While this is interesting (and a bit terrifying) I don't really see how this related to the line continuation \.

Comment: The backslash is optional here, which makes it a bit more terrifying I guess.

Comment: This is a good example of a gotcha with implied continuation. The linter I use doesn't warn about it either.

Comment: @gregrf At the risk of shameless self-promotion I wrote a [small helper program for this](https://github.com/congma/checkimpcont), but currently it's Python-2 only. It originated from some other stackoverflow discussions (see the readme file there).

Answer (score 6):

One case I can think of is when the programmer forgets a `\`.  This is especially likely when someone comes and adds values at a later date.  Though this example is still somewhat contrived because the continuation lines have to have the same indentation level (otherwise it would fail with an IndentationError).

Example:

```
a = 1 \
+ 2 \
+ 3
assert a == 6
```

Later, someone adds a line:

```
a = 1 \
+ 2 \
+ 3    # Whoops, forgot to add \ !
+ 4
assert a == 10  # Nope
```

Comment: What is outcome of last example?

Comment: @variable `a == 6`, and the last `+4` is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

I think like @0x5453, if you wrongly add backslash to your code.
This backslash cause the comment to be concat with a.

```
a = "Some text. " \
"""Here are some multiline comments
that will be added to a"""
```