# What does "\" mean in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting

I encountered this code while studying String Formatting Operators in Python:

```
print('%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.'%\
     {"language":"Python", "number":2})
```

What does "\" represent in this code?

Comment: It is an unnecessary line continuation character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830681/is-line-continuation-with-backslash-dangerous-in-python

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [Python's documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/slash.html) a back slash breaks the line of code allowing for the next line continuation.